# position absolute + <body> position relative

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im redesigning a vary old page. In order to make the menu system work, they use position: relative; on the `<body>` tag. My problem is that when I for example create a jQuery ui datepicker or something that is positioned absolute, it gets shown +- ~200px to left/right. Is there any workaround to this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a container `<div>` around the entire page and set that to `position: relative` instead.

Comment: What differece would that make?

Comment: @Johan: The DatePicker would be added to the (`static`) `<body>` instead.

Comment: Well, if the div is inside the body, wouldnt the datepicker relate to the div position?

Comment: No, it wouldn't... the element itself is added to the body. (Unless something's changed recently? Have you tried it?)

Comment: Thanks, made some small modifications to the code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a very old post but if this helps anyone else out there, this problem might be occurring due to the margin on the left side of the body.

A simple fix could be to counter the margin before the datepicker shows up.

```
$('#container').datepicker(
{
    beforeShow: function(inputElem, dp)
    {
        dp.dpDiv.css({ marginLeft: '-' + $('body').css('margin-left') });
    }
});
```